# Why does this HTML code only works properly when I echo it with PHP?

Tags: php, html, refresh, captcha

I am using the Captcha made by Securimage.

When I write the following code in HTML section:

```
<tr>

<td><img id='captcha' src='/securimage/securimage_show.php' height='50' 
width='135' alt='CAPTCHA Image' /><br>

<a href='' onclick=\"document.getElementById('captcha').src
'/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false\">
[ Different Image ]</a></td>
<td><input type='text' name='captcha_code' size='20' maxlength='6' /></td>

<tr>
```

... And I click on "Different image" to change the captcha, the whole page refresh, thus losing all text entered into text fields.

But when I take all that code and put it into PHP echo statement, the captcha changes without refreshing the whole page (which is what I want)

Do you guys know why does this happen? This is really disturbing!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try getting rid of the `\"` around the `onclick`.  You don't need escaped quotes.

Comment: Hi Rocket, thanks for your response. Yes, removing the backslashes did solve my problem. I don't understand why this would cause html to trigger refresh.. 
Thanks again

Comment: It's "refreshing" the page, because the `href` is `''`, which means the same page.  The `onclick` is not being read because oh the `\"`s, so it just follows the link normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the backslashes from the onclick attribute.  When you echo that from PHP, perhaps PHP melts them out.

Comment: Hi schtever, yes you are right. Thanks for that.
As I said in the comment above, I find it weird that a backslash would cause the html to refresh the whole page.
Thanks a lot

Comment: "perhaps PHP melts them out".  `echo "\""` this prints a `"`.  You need to escape quotes inside quotes.

Comment: @eric01: It's not refreshing, per se.  It's following the `href`, as the `onclick` isn't being read.

Comment: The backslash was preventing the browser from recognizing your `onclick` attribute. Since your `href` attribute is empty, your link essentially points to the current URL. So when you clicked the link, your `onclick` handler didn't fire, it never returned `false` to cancel the default event, and the browser redirected to the target of your link, which was the current page.

Comment: Oh ok, inside quotes, I got it. Thanks everyone for your help